# Proof for this set to be compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

I'm trying to prove (or confute) that the set
$$\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1]$$
is compact.

So here is my work so far.

First of all, compact = closed and bounded.

About the closure, I thought of this: I can write the set as

$$\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1] = \bigcup_{i, j} \{\frac{a_i}{b_j}\} \qquad a_i, b_j \in\mathbb{Z} \quad 0 \leq \frac{a_i}{b_j} \leq 1$$

Which means a countable-infinite union of singletons.

Now, since they are singletons, they are closed sets. Indeed we know that $A$ is open if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists x \in A$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset A$.

In singletons this condition is violated, hence they are not open.

Also the complementary of this union of singletons is a union of open sets, which is open. Hence this union of singleton is closed.

I don't know if is there a better (or right, if this is wrong) way to prove the closure...

About the bounded part, I thought that this comes from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ intersects a bounded set, that is $[0, 1]$.
If the set were $(0, 1)$ then it wouldn't have been bounded, hence not compact.

Please tell me if I'm wrong, of if there is some more elegant way to proceed.

**Reference Request**

Is there some good book, or online notes, where I can find similar exercises, possibly with solutions?

Comment: A union of infinitely many singletons need not be closed. Take $a_n=1/n$ for example. It isn’t closed since $0$ is not an element of the set.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1]$ is not compact.

Comment: @Clayton Uhm, ok. But I don't understand how that example proves the non closure of my set

Comment: @geetha290krm Magic.

Comment: Compact does not equal closed and bounded.  Compact sets are closed and bounded but closed and bounded sets are only compact if they are complete. The rational numbers are not complete.

Comment: @JohnDouma closed and bounded does equal compact for subsets of $\mathbb R$. This set is not closed. (If you’re viewing it as a subspace of itself, then yes, closed and bounded does not suffice for metric spaces in general and the issue is completeness).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The set in question is a subset of the rationals and is not complete.

Comment: @JohnDouma It’s a subset of the reals too. If they were thinking of it as a subset of $\mathbb Q$ the proof that it’s closed would be very short.

Comment: "...the complementary of this union of singletons is a union of open sets..." NO. It is an intersection of open sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not compact. Take $a_n = \sum_{k = 2}^n \frac{1}{k!}$, which is always a rational number bewteen $0$ and $1$, but it converges toward $e - 2$, which is irrational. $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. It is even dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't understand the proof for that set to be not closed. Unless you are using a sequence $a_n$, telling me that the finite sequence always converges to a rational number but the infinite does not. Can you expand a bit?

Comment: For each $n$, $a_n$ is the sum $1/2! + 1/3! + \cdots + 1/n!$. It is rational by finite sum of rational numbers. However, $(a_n)$ converges toward the irrational numer $e - 2 = \sum_{k \geqslant 0} 1/k! = 1/2! + 1/3! + \cdots$. Therefore, it is not closed.

Answer (score 3):

Take your favorite irrational number between $0$ and $1$; mine is $a=\pi-3=0.14159265\cdots$. Let $a_n$ be the truncation of $a$ to $n$ decimal places, so for my example we have $a_0=0$, $a_1=0.1$, $a_2=0.14$, $a_3=0.141$, and so on.

Then every open neighborhood of $a$ must include some $a_n$ sufficiently nearby, showing $a$ is a limit point of $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ that does not belong to $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$. Thus $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ is not closed.